# Calculating decibel values from live microphone audio using alsaaudio

Tags: python, audio, alsa, pyalsaaudio

I have this Python script that I'm running on my Ubuntu laptop to get the live ambient noise levels from the microphone on the laptop. I don't think this script works well though and I can't figure out why. I suspected it might just be a long period size but I'm not sure if that's it. Can someone help me understand what's wrong with this script? Thank you!

```
import alsaaudio
import audioop
import time
import math

# Set the audio parameters
device = 'default'
channels = 1  # mono
sample_rate = 44100  # 44.1 kHz
format = alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE

# Open the audio input stream
inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL, device)
inp.setchannels(channels)
inp.setrate(sample_rate)
inp.setformat(format)
inp.setperiodsize(256)

# Main loop to continuously print audio levels
try:
    while True:
        # Read audio data from the microphone
        _, data = inp.read()

        # Calculate the peak audio level in decibels
        rms = audioop.rms(data, 2)  # 2 for sample width 16-bit

        # Print the decibel level without dynamic range adjustment
        decibels = 20 * math.log10(rms)
        print(f"Decibels: {decibels:.2f} dB")

        time.sleep(0.01)  # Adjust the sleep duration as needed

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopping the script.")
```

I expect this script to be sensitive and show an immediate jump in the decibel values if I make a sound. That unfortunately is not the case right now and I'm not sure why. I used the sounddevice library and it seems to work well but I can't get the same result with pyalsaaudio.

EDIT:
Based on comments by @fdcpp, I have modified my script and I get negative values and don't know why

```
import alsaaudio
import audioop
import math
import struct

# Set the audio parameters
device = 'default'
channels = 1  # mono
sample_rate = 44100  # 44.1 kHz
format = alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE

# Open the audio input stream
inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL, device, channels=channels, rate=sample_rate, format=format, periodsize=1024)

# Main loop to continuously print audio levels
try:
    while True:
        # Read audio data from the microphone
        _, data = inp.read()

        # Convert byte data to 16-bit integer format. Have tried with and without this and get the same result.
        samples = struct.unpack('<' + ('h' * (len(data) // 2)), data)

        # Calculate the peak audio level in decibels
        peak_amplitude = max(map(abs, samples))

        # Convert amplitude to decibels
        decibels = 20 * math.log10(peak_amplitude / 32767)  # Assuming 16-bit audio
        print(f"Decibels: {decibels:.2f} dB")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopping the script.")
```

Comment: `PCM_NORMAL` means the `.read()` function is blocking, so you can get rid of the `time.sleep` which will lose you 10ms. Given 256 is only ~5ms of audio, you will lose a minimum of two buffers. The `read` function should [return a negative value](https://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/libalsaaudio.html#alsaaudio.PCM.read) you can test against if you are losing buffers. If you are looking for transient behaviour, you probably just want peaks rather than RMS. dBFS RMS is not going to   provide a lot of useful information.

Comment: @fdcpp Thanks for the feedback, I'll make those changes. How can I get the peaks you mentioned?
peak_amplitude = audioop.max(data, 2) ?

Comment: You can take each buffer of day from `.read` and apply `abs` then `max` functions to it. That will give you the highest peak for that buffer.

Comment: Be aware that `data` _may_ beat in a byte format and have to be reassembled into 16bit integer format first

Comment: @fdcpp I tried to do what you said but I still get negative db values. Maybe I did something wrong? I've added the modified script

Comment: dBFS will more than likely be less than 0, so that sounds normal. Also, I see you used `map`, not `abs` the audioop `max` function is easier as you have used in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @fdcpp's comments, this seems to work well.

```
import alsaaudio
import audioop
import math

# Set the audio parameters
device = 'default'
sample_rate = 44100  # 44.1 kHz

# Open the audio input stream
inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL, device, channels=1, rate=sample_rate, format=alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE, periodsize=1024)


# Main loop to continuously print audio levels
try:
    while True:
        # Read audio data from the microphone
        _, data = inp.read()

        # Calculate the peak audio level in decibels
        peak_amplitude = audioop.max(data, 2)

        # Convert amplitude to decibels
        decibels = 20 * math.log10(peak_amplitude)  # Assuming 16-bit audio
        print(f"Decibels: {decibels:.2f} dB")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopping the script.")
```